# Could not understand keras dense layer's output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am testing keras layer. I have built a simple dense layer with input shape is `(10,2)` and all value equals 1. And I use zero_initial_state to initial layer weights. However, I could not understand the output of the dense layer since it may  compute the final outputs with sth. unknown. My code is:

```
batch_size = 10
time_steps = 30
label_num = 2.
units = 5

batch_data = tf.ones((batch_size, label_num))

dense_layer = Dense(units)
output = dense_layer(batch_data)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  sess.run(init)
  print('__________________output_____________________')
  print(sess.run(output))
```

I print the intial kernel and bias:

```
____________________self.kernel____________________

[[-0.6072792   0.87520194 -0.5916964  -0.28233814  0.37042332]
 [ 0.24503589 -0.8950937  -0.7122175   0.67322683  0.9035703 ]]

____________________self.bias____________________

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

I think the final output should be:

```
[[-0.3622433  -0.01989174 -1.3039138   0.3908887   1.2739936 ]
 [-0.3622433  -0.01989174 -1.3039138   0.3908887   1.2739936 ]
 [-0.3622433  -0.01989174 -1.3039138   0.3908887   1.2739936 ]
 [-0.3622433  -0.01989174 -1.3039138   0.3908887   1.2739936 ]
 ....
```

However, the final output is:

```
[[-0.25280607  1.0728977  -0.6096982   1.1957564   0.82103825]
 [-0.25280607  1.0728977  -0.6096982   1.1957564   0.82103825]
 [-0.25280607  1.0728977  -0.6096982   1.1957564   0.82103825]
```

Activation is None. Why the output of the keras dense layer is this ?

Comment: You don't understand the shape of the output or numerical result of `output`? You know that weights initialized randomly everytime, right?

Comment: As @Vlad pointed out, Dense uses `kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'` by default. And you said that you're using zero_initial_state to initial layer weights

Comment: I find that I have made a big mistake. When I print the weights, I reintialize all variables. So the output is the result based on the last random intial weights which is different from the first one that I have printed!